# How to get Bash command history statistics, like the most used commands in the last 6 months?

Tags: bash

How can I see, for example, what are my most used commands in the last 6 months in bash? Can I store this data somewhere?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
history|awk '{print $2}'|awk 'BEGIN {FS="|"} {print $1}'|sort|uniq -c|sort -rn|head -30
```

From a thread on the Arch Linux boards

Comment: It really should skip "sudo" as the first word and go further

Answer (score 1):

You want the `lastcomm` command.  You'll need to install and/or activate the "acct" package - how to do this depends on your operating system.

Comment: I tried this and got `lastcomm: /var/account/acct: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how far back it will go, but bash's `history` command will tell you your previous commands. Maybe it can be configured to store up to 6 months of data and then a grep/sed/etc spell can tell you what you want?