# Most used command combos in bash history?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

There are nice oneliners to show the [most used commands in bash history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355005/how-to-get-bash-command-history-statistics-like-the-most-used-commands-in-the-l) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18301908/create-a-histogram-or-frequency-list-of-most-popular-commands-used-in-bash-sessi). Now that I optimized my aliases, this only shows me shortcuts.

As a next step, I want to optimize for combos. For example, I believe I often do a combo of git-log, git-show, git-push. I would like to have some hard data to back this up, though. There might also be combos to discover I would not have considered.

So, the input is a history of commands. The output should be something like:

```
123 git log
    git show
    git push
456 git show
    git log
    git push
```

Syntax whatever. It could as well be this, if simpler:

```
123 git log; git show; git push
456 git show; git log; git push
```

It should probably be parameterized for the number of commands to consider, although 2 and 3 are the only ones that matter for me now.

Question: Is there a nice oneliner to compute that?

Comment: Is there a question here, any particular part you are stuck on?

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Comment: Ok, added the actual question. :)

Answer (score 2):

There are issues with format in the history file, (and the name, I believe the default is `.bash_history` but I used `.bash-history`), but a first pass could be something as simple as:

```
sed /^#/d ~/.bash-history | 
    awk '{a2=a1; a1=$0;} NR>2{a[$0 ";" a1";" a2]++} 
        END {for (c in a) print a[c], c}'
```

Comment: `HISTFILE` environment variable would point to the history file

Comment: I'm not sure about the awk, but the three-tuple's first entries are always the same. I get results like "cd;cd;ls".

Comment: Not surprising, since you use `cd` and `ls` a lot.  You can filter out common commands in the sed (I was using it to just filter out timestamp lines that begin with a comment), but you could use `sed -e '/#/d' -e '/^cd$/d' -e '/^ls$/d' `

Comment: Or just `awk '/^cd$/ || /^ls$/ || /^#/ { next } {a2=a1; ...`